# Stark Effect in Hydrogen Degenerate Perturbation Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, eigenvalue

I am going though [this](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Quantum_Physics_(Ackland)/03%3A_Dealing_with_Degeneracy/3.03%3A_example_of_degenerate_perturbation_theory_-_Stark_Effect_in_Hydrogen) example of degenerate perturbation theory.

We are examining the Stark effect in hydrogen for $n=2$. After finding the 4 degenerate cases; $|0, 0⟩, |1,0⟩, |1,1⟩, |1,-1⟩$, we apply the perturbation $\hat{V} = eEr\cos{\theta}$. The matrix representation of the perturbation is:

$$\hat{V} = \begin{bmatrix}0&-3eEa_0 & 0 & 0\\-3eEa_0&0 &0 &0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Finding the eigenvalues of this perturbation gives: $\Delta E = -3eEa_0,0,0,3eEa_0$.

Whats throwing me of is knowing what eigenvalue applies to what original degenerate case. In the text, they say that $|1,1⟩$ and $|1,-1⟩$ degeneracy is not lifted, but provide no real explanation.

Basically, how do I keep track of what eigenvalue belongs to what solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix contains a (degenerate) subspace spanned by $\vert 1,1\rangle$ and $\vert 1,-1\rangle$ by simple inspection of the original ordering of the basis states.

The similarity transformation $T$ that will bring $\hat V$ to diagonal form $T^{-1}VT$ will only mix $\vert 0,0\rangle$ and $\vert 1,0\rangle$, again by inspection: this similarity transformation will be of the form
$$
T=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&0&0\\
-1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right)
$$
since there only mixing of the $m=0$ states, again by inspection of your $\hat V$.

Thus, the subspace spanned by $\{\vert 1,\pm 1\rangle\}$ will remain unchanged by the mixing of $\vert 0,0\rangle$ and $\vert 1,0\rangle$ states.  Your final basis will be $\vert\psi_\pm\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert 0,0\rangle\pm \vert 1,0\rangle\right),\vert\phi_\pm\rangle = \vert 1,\pm 1\rangle$.  The eigenvalues for the $m=\pm 1$ states remain unchanged as they were unaffected by $T$.